# Has a general aviation twin-engine turboprop with counter rotating propellors ever been built?

Tags: general-aviation, propeller, turboprop

In my experience with general aviation twin-engine turboprops I've never heard of one with counter rotating propellors. I've never seen any data about an engine manufacturer building left-rotating turboprop engines.

I'm also curious if any counter rotating twin-engine turboprop aircraft exist outside general aviation as well.

Answer (score 8):

The only aircraft with turboprop counter rotating propellers that I can think of is the Piaggio P 180 *Avanti*, whose design is unusual in so many ways.

Check out http://www.mpa.piaggioaerospace.it/, which gives the specifications of a Maritime Patrol Aircraft(MPA) based on the P 180.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know the P.180 has counter rotating props. Thanks for that.

Comment: I wonder how they achieve the left hand rotation. Is it reversed by the gearbox or is the whole engine built reversed?

Comment: In these cases, only the gearbox is reversed; rebuilding the engine is too complicated and simply not worth it.

Comment: I wonder if one gear box is heavier than the other.

Comment: I too would be interested to know more about the gearbox differences.

Comment: Damn beautiful aircraft.